# Adding together values from all returned rowsz

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a very basic quote website for my college, where students can submit quotes and then vote on them. Votes are stored in a `votes` table, which contains the `id`, `quoteid` ,`value` and `IP` (to try to prevent spam voting). When someone votes it inserts a new row, containing the `quoteid`, and a `value`. This `value` can be 1 or -1. I have written a function which returns an array of all votes with a specific quote number.

Now, what I have to do is write a function so that all the `value` field are added together, giving a total score. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it like you said. Change your query to use SUM() and group by quoteid. Example below:

```
SELECT quoteid, SUM(value) total from votes GROUP BY quoteid
```

Comment: I just tried using `SUM(action) total FROM votes WHERE quoteid = ?` however it tells me that I have a syntax error.

Comment: Gist your whole query

Answer (score 0):

Better if you count all in query.

```
 <?php  
   function getVotes($quoteId) {
    $sql = "Select count(id) as voteup from votes where `value` = 1 and quote_id = {$quoteId} 
                union
                Select count(id) as votedown from votes where `value` = -1 and quote_id = {$quoteId}";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // haven't read while loop because we know the result is only one row
     return $data ;//data is array with voteup and votedown keys
    }
```

> **NOTE:** The mysql_ functions are deprecated, better if you'll use PDO or mysqli, i have wrote for example.